# Ansible : Execute commands on newly created EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have an Ansible configuration where I am creating an EC2 instance. After the instance is ready, I want to disable periodic apt updates and wait for current update process to finish. Whenever I add the config in yml file, it executes the command on my local system. What am I doing wrong?

yml file:

```
---
  - name: Provision an EC2 Instance
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: False
    tags: provisioning
 tasks:

      - name: Create New security group with below given name
        local_action:
          module: ec2_group
          name: "{{ security_group }}"
          description: Security Group for Newly Created EC2 Instance
          region: "{{ region }}"
          rules:
            - proto: tcp
              from_port: 22
              to_port: 22
              cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
            - proto: tcp
              from_port: 80
              to_port: 80
              cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
          rules_egress:
            - proto: all
              cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0


      - name: Launch the new t2 micro EC2 Instance
        local_action: ec2
                      group={{ security_group }}
                      instance_type={{ instance_type}}
                      image={{ image }}
                      wait=true
                      region={{ region }}
                      keypair={{ keypair }}
                      count={{count}}
        register: ec2
```

Now, after this, I wait for ssh to finish and want to pass the following commands on the newly created Ec2 instance :

```
- name: Disable timers for unattended upgrade, so that none will be triggered by the `date -s` call.
  raw: systemctl disable --now {{item}}
  with_items:
    - 'apt-daily.timer'
    - 'apt-daily-upgrade.timer'

- name: Reload systemctl daemon to apply the new changes
  raw: systemctl daemon-reload

- name: Purge autoupdate
  raw: apt -y purge unattended-upgrades    

- name: Update apt cache
  raw: apt -y update
```

But adding them as raw is not working, or even adding them as command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first section of code you posted is provisioning a new EC2 instance by making calls to the AWS API from your local system:

```yaml
  - name: Provision an EC2 Instance
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: False
...
 - name: Create New security group with below given name
   local_action:
     module: ec2_group
```

Note the `local_action` section that specifies running an action locally. Also, your target is `localhost`.

If you then want to then configure the new system, you can add it to a host group and run some configuration steps. For example, add this following the `Provision an EC2 Instance` step to add the new instance's public IP to a hostgroup called `ec2hosts`:

```bash
   - name: Add instance public IP to host group
     add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groups=ec2hosts
     loop: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

Now you can configure the host by targeting the host group:

```yaml
- hosts: ec2hosts
  name: configuration play
  user: ec2-user
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
  - name:  Disable timers for unattended upgrade, so that none will be triggered by the `date -s` call.
    raw: systemctl disable --now {{item}}
    with_items:
      - 'apt-daily.timer'
      - 'apt-daily-upgrade.timer'

  - name: Reload systemctl daemon to apply the new changes
    raw: systemctl daemon-reload

  - name: Purge autoupdate
    raw: apt -y purge unattended-upgrades    

  - name: Update apt cache
    raw: apt -y update
```

To summarize, you first create the instance from your local system, wait for it to boot, add its IP address to a host group, then run additional configuration steps by running ansible against that host group. For this to work, make sure to use an SSH key pair for which the private key has been added to the SSH agent. Also, make sure to launch the EC2 instance in to a public subnet.

Refer to the [Ansible Amazon Web Service Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_aws.html).

Comment: I will try this out. Thanks. :-)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. Just to clarify, I need to add the ssh key pair in local ssh agent, right?

Comment: Yes. Your local agent will use the private key when prompted by the new instance's SSH server.